# Why does my javascript here, takes about 5 clicks for the onclick to work?

Tags: javascript

I have a submit button on a landing page. but whenever people hit that landing page the first time, it doesnt work.
The onclick takes about 2-5 clicks for it to even work??? Whenever I click on the button the first few times doesnt work, until after.

```
 var subscribe = function(email) {

    var es = document.getElementsByClassName("email-submit");
    var fb = document.getElementsByClassName("floatingBarsG");
    var ea = document.getElementsByClassName("email-text");
    var et = document.getElementsByClassName("email-thanks");


    if (email=="" || !/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/.test(email)) /* ' */ {


        ea[0].style.backgroundColor = "#f4bfbf";
        setTimeout(function() {ea[0].style.backgroundColor = "#fff";}, 250);

        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            $(".cta").load("step2.html");
            $(".cta-email").html("<h1>Thank You for Signing Up!</h1>");
        }

    }
    var params = "email="+email;
    xmlhttp.open("POST","s",true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(params);
}

//capture events

var init = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("email-submit")[0].onclick = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        subscribe(e.target.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("email-text")[0].value);
    }

    document.getElementsByClassName("email-text")[0].onkeypress = function(e) {
       if(e.keyCode == 13) {
            e.preventDefault();
            subscribe(e.target.value);
        }
    }

}
if(window.addEventListener){
    window.addEventListener('load',init,false);
} else {
    window.attachEvent('onload',init);
}
```

Comment: Define 'not work'. do your click handlers fire from the start? Or this there something not working in your `subscribe` method. If so define exactly what it is thats not working.

Comment: the onkeypress keycode 13 "enter" works right away on the form field, but it seems like users have to click on the top right corner of the button for it to work.

Comment: ` <button type="submit" class="email-submit"><span>Sign Up Now</span></button>`